# How to integrate bootstrap 5 in nuxtjs?

Tags: vue.js, twitter-bootstrap, nuxt.js, bootstrap-5, server-side-rendering

First, I tried integrating bootstrap-vue, but that supports bootstrap 4, and worse vue2.
So I'm trying to integrate bootstrap 5 without any changes by following these steps:

1. I install the bootstrap package (via npm).
2. So I'm going to edit the nuxt.config.ts file, adding the css files in the css array and the script in the plugin entry.

This is the final result:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
   plugins: [
     {
       src: "~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
       mode: "clients",
     },
   ],
   css: [
     "~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
     "@/assets/css/global.css",
   ],
});
```

Now the css works fine, the problem remains with the js file.
I don't understand why, but nothing animated works, starting from dropdowns, to carousels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed some older StackOverflow answers and managed (I think) to create working demo with newest Nuxt 3 and Bootstrap 5 like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-bebg1r-j6lqxm

The key things:

1. In `package.json` add and install dependencies for `bootstrap`, `sass` and `sass-loader`
2. Create `.scss` file in `/assets` folder containg `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`
3. Load this file in `nuxt.config.ts` via `css: ['~/assets/main.scss']`
4. Plugin to load JS bundle in `/plugins/bootstrap.client.ts`

Answer (score 0):

So step 1 is to install dependencies:
if using npm its

1. npm i bootstrap
2. npm i sass -D
3. npm i sass-loader -D

if using yarn just replace npm i with yarn add.

Then you create a folder called plugins. in this folder you create a new file for example useBootstrap.client.ts

in this file, you paste the following code:

```
import * as bootstrap from 'bootstrap'

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
    return {
        provide: {
            bootstrap: bootstrap
        }
    }
})
```

Then you create a folder called scss in the assets directory, normally you will want to call it main.scss

then you add the following line: `@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';`

Your last step is to load in your main.scss in your nuxt.config.ts:

```
css: [
'@/assets/scss/main.scss'
],
```

Now most of Bootstrap works. Maybe your tooltips or modals might require some extra config or libraries.